# GenericServlet in java-2 init methods

Tags: java, servlets

GenericServlet class has two init methods. Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29) is clear as to why:

`init()`:

> A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need to call super.init(config).
>   Instead of overriding `init(ServletConfig)`, simply override this method and it will be called by `GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config)`. The `ServletConfig` object can still be retrieved via `getServletConfig()`.

So if your servlet doesn't care about the `ServletConfig`, then just implement `init()`.

Comment: @Abkutty: A "convenience method" is one that is provided as an easy alternative to the "full" method.

Answer (score 2):

There are two init() methods as part of generic servlet class.

1. init(ServletConfig config)
2. init()

Sample servlet program for understanding the 2 init() and their usages.

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void init() throws......
    {
        System.out.println("we are in 2nd init() ");
    }
    public void service(HttpServlet.........)throws .....{
        System.out.println("we are in TestServlet");
    }

}
```

Steps carried out when the above servlet is deployed in the server.

1. After deploying the project, when ever the client sends the request for the first time to
   TestServlet then server creates the testServlet object and then calls first init()
   method (init(ServletConfig config)). Then JVM checks for the first init() method in
   TestServlet as it is not available then it checks in super class HttpServlet there also
   first init method is not available then JVM checks in super class of HttpServlet i.e
   GenericServlet class there first init() is availble then JVM executes it and calls the
   second init() as the second init() is directly availble in the TestServlet then JVM
   executes it.

-->It is not at all recomended to use first init() method when ever we are using HttpServlet.

-->What were the problems and why we we are not recomended to use first init()?

First approach:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
      public void init(ServletConfig config) throws.....
      {
        config=getServletConfig();
        String paramName = config.getInitParameter("ParameterName");
        System.out.println("paramName");
      }
    public void service(HttpServlet request ..........)throws .......
    {
        System.out.println("we are in 2nd service method()");
    }

}
```

Following steps are carried out when the above servlet is deployed.
a.Servlet Object is created and all the instance variables of super class are declared with default value i.e null Then JVM executes first init() method as it was availbel in TestServlet it executes it but getServletConfig () is availble in GenericServlet so config is set to null when ever client sends request for TestServlet we will face Null Pointer Execpetion.

Second approach

```
//Sample code
  ServletConfig config;
public void init(ServletConfig config){
    this.config=config;
    String fileName = config.getInitParameter("ParameterName");
    System.out.println(config);
}
```

The above code looks good but the problem with the above code is redundancy, According to inheritance rules redundant code should be removed.

Third approach:

```
//approach1 problem can be resolved by calling the super class init() so that config object 
//will returned which we can use in init() of our servlet.
super.init(config);
config=getServletConfig();
```

So for the above resons Sun has recomended to use 2nd init() as part of our servlet .As we are not providing the first init() as part of our code then JVM will calls the first init() method of GenericServlet .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, genericServlet does nothing, there are two init method

1)  init()  : A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need to call 
    super.init(config).

2)  init(ServletConfig config) : Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that
    the servlet is being placed into service.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever send the first request web container always calls init(ServletConfig config)method.Because of to store config object in the feature purpose and then internal calls init()method .Highly recommended to override init()method.In this method to initialize your own activities.that's way simply saying init(servletConfig config) is meant for web container purpose  and init() method meant for programmer purpose.that's way GenericServlet contains two init()methods.